# how to get the ouput of all paragraphs data in XSLT

Tags: xslt

This is my XML

```
<p>test1</p>
<p>test2<p>
<p>test3</p>
<p>test4</p>
```

HI here i have problem when working with for each loop to display the all paragraphs in above.

When i use forech loop for this,i am getting only the first value **test1**

Her is my code

```
<xsl:for-each select="root">

              <xsl:value-of select="root/p"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
```

out put is coming like this
test1
test1
test1
test1
Can any one give the solution for this .i will pleasure to them

**Desired output**
I want display like
test1
test2
test3
test4

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/p">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```